# How do I stop rainwater from coming into carport?

Tags: carport

How do I stop rainwater from coming on my carport from the driveway and what supplies do I need to fix it?

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Hi... Take the [tour] and look at other questions that have been asked.  You will notice that successful questions have a great deal more detail in them. You can [edit] your question to add the detail to better describe how your carport is built, the nature of the problem, and maybe some photos that show what makes your situation different from the next person's.

Comment: Do you have access to a level?  The driveway should slope downward away from where you don't want water to pool.  Test that and see if the options presented in the answer are feasible.

Comment: If you could [edit] a photo of the driveway/carport area into your question then we could be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

3 options:

- Raise the carport above the level of the driveway

  - **Supplies needed:**
  - Tools to break up the carport floor
  - Fill material to raise the carport
  - New material (dirt? gravel? concrete?) to fashion the new garage floor
  - Additional material to slope driveway up to meet new garage floor elevation
- Lower the driveway so it slopes away from the carport

  - **Supplies needed:**
  - Tools to break up driveway
  - Wheelbarrow(s) and truck(s) to haul excess driveway material away
  - New material to resurface driveway to desired spec
- Install a drain between the driveway and the carport

  - **Supplies needed:**
  - Tools to break up a small band of the driveway, just before the carport
  - Tools to dig a trench for the drain to run somewhere else (likely the same tools as above)
  - Gravel to back fill the drain trench
  - Perforated pipe to act as a drain pipe
  - Non-perf pipe to direct the water away to "somewhere else"
  - Grate material to cover the top of the drain trench between the driveway and carport
  - Fill material to top over the drain to "somewhere else"

I'm sure there are many, many more details, but, based on the little we got, that's about the best I can do.